# Why does it report this error when I use pytorchnlp-GloVe?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, pytorch

```
from torchnlp.word_to_vector import GloVe
vectors = GloVe()
vectors['hello']
```

RuntimeError: Vector for token Bolonia has 147 dimensions, but previously read vectors have 300 dimensions. All vectors must have the same number of dimensions.

Comment: Did you modify the embeddings file or iterrupted downloading?

Comment: No, I didn't change it and interrupt its download. However, I suspect that the information is incomplete because the file resources are on a foreign server (I am in China, and the connection to the external network is restricted) and the download is unstable?

Comment: Or is it a problem with the Python version?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have solved this problem. It was caused by the memory overflow caused by the loaded embedded file being too large. I modified the parameters for initializing GloVe and replaced it with a smaller embedded file and it was successful.